# C# How to create a List of objects with read only properties by passing in a list of similar objects via constructor

Tags: c#

My class is defined as follows. Without going too much into detail I don't want anyone to be able to alter this instantiated object, or the object that is passed in to this classes constructor.

```
public class ItemDeliveryInfo
{
    public ItemDeliveryAudit ItemDeliveryAudit
    {
        get
        {
            return this._itemDeliveryAudit;
        }
    }
    public int ItemDeliveryAuditId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ItemDeliveryAudit.ItemDeliveryAuditId;
        }
    }
    public int? DeliveryDriverId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ItemDeliveryAudit.DeliveryDriverId;
        }
    }
    public int DeliveryId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ItemDeliveryAudit.DeliveryId;
        }
    }
    public int StoreId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ItemDeliveryAudit.StoreId;
        }
    }

    private ItemDeliveryAudit _itemDeliveryAudit;
    private bool _isItemLate;
    private bool _isItemOnTime;

    internal ItemDeliveryInfo(ItemDeliveryAudit itemDeliveryAudit, bool itemLate, bool itemOnTime)
    {
        this._itemDeliveryAudit = drAssignedAudit;
        this._isItemLate = itemLate;
        this._isItemOnTime = itemOnTime;
    }
    public bool IsItemLate()
    {
        return this._isItemLate;
    }

    public bool IsItemOnTime()
    {
        return this._isItemOnTime;
    }
}
```

Currently the constructor works for creating a singular ItemDeliveryInfo object and successfully returns the object I want...

```
 ItemDeliveryInfo infoObject = new ItemDeliveryInfo(itemAudit, true, false);
```

However, I cannot wrap my head around having a constructor that would be executed as follows...

```
List<ItemDeliveryAudits> itemDeliveryAudits = // code to populate list to pass to the ctor;
List<ItemDeliveryInfo> itemDeliveryInfos = new ItemDeliveryInfo(itemDeliveryAudits, true, false);
```

I'm assuming that I will have to create another overloaded constructor to handle this, but I am just at a loss for how to accomplish this. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use LINQ and the current ctor:

```
List<ItemDeliveryInfo> itemDeliveryInfos = 
          itemDeliveryAudits.Select(i => new ItemDeliveryInfo(i, true, false)).ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked. Kudos for the fast response!

Answer (score 1):

If you do "new ItemDeliveryInfo" you'll always get a single instance of "ItemDeliveryInfo." There's no way for a constructor to return anything other than the type that it's a constructor for - it's decidedly *not* possible to do something like

```
List<ItemDeliveryInfo> itemDeliveryInfos = new ItemDeliveryInfo(itemDeliveryAudits, true, false);
```

You could accomplish what you want by creating a static method or factory like the following:

```
public static List<ItemDeliveryInfo> GetItemDeliveryInfo(List<ItemDeliveryAudits> audits) {
   var list = new List<ItemDeliveryinfo>();
   foreach (var deliveryAudit in audits)
   {
       list.Add(new ItemDeliveryInfo(deliveryAudit));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ:

```
List<ItemDeliveryAudits> itemDeliveryAudits = // code to populate list to pass to the ctor;
List<ItemDeliveryInfo> itemDeliveryInfos = itemDeliveryAudits
    .Select(item => new ItemDeliveryInfo(item, true, false))
    .ToList();
```